# Why is numpy importation failing?

Tags: python, numpy

I have installed Python 2.7.12 and I also tried to install numpy, scipy.

When I try to import numpy with this statement:

```
 import numpy
```

It returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

After this I searched and I found an installer called Anaconda, but despite I downloaded and executed it, it stills failing.

Could you help me please?

**EDIT**

This is what I did to install numpy

[image]

Comment: where did you download numpy from?  you should use pip in all fairness

Comment: @Naib look the edited post please

Comment: Please paste text not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an alternative I recommend reinstall Anaconda package:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
```

next

```
conda update conda

conda update anaconda
```

Comment: Solved! I do not know what happened but now I can import numpy without problem!